# Simple Excel VBA – copy pasting to another workbook

Tags: vba, excel

I've looked at couple of codes on copy pasting from one excel workbook to another. For some reason, I am getting errors even when I am directly copying the format. My code is only ~12 lines so far, so if you could look and see what the issue is, that would be really great help to me. Thank you very much!

```
Sub UpdateActualWorkbook()

    Sheets("Input").Select
    Range("BE9").Select
    Selection.Copy

    Dim Display As String
    Display = Cells(1, 2).Value

    If Display = "Yes" Then

    Dim wb As Workbook
    Set wb = Workbooks.Open("Book1")
    wb.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1").PasteSpecial

End If
End Sub
```

Currently I am getting an error message on wb.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1").PasteSpecial
^this line. This does not change whether I make it .Paste or .Pastespecial.

I would be really grateful if anyone could help me. Thank you so much!

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: `Workbooks.Open("Book1")`?

Comment: it's giving me the error: "Object doesn't support this property or method."

Answer (score 1):

If:

```
Set wb = Workbooks.Open("Book1")
```

fails, then `wb` will be `Nothing` and the `PasteSpecial` line will raise an error.  If you simply want to add a new workbook, then use:

```
Set wb = Workbooks.Add
```

and if you want to open an existing workbook, then give the full filespec.

Comment: Thank you so much! As an update, I now have the file path to the existing workbook. Now it's giving me the error: "Object doesn't support this property or method." The bug seems to be in the wb.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1").Paste. The workbook does open fine though – do you have any suggestions on how I should approach this?

Answer (score 0):

I know it late but try this...

```
Sub tstcpy()
If Cells(1, 2).Value = “yes” Then
Workbooks("Book1a.xlsm").Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(9, 2).Copy _
Destination:=Workbooks("Book2.xlsx").Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(1, 1)
End If

End Sub
```